# compare the length of two variable

Tags: c#

I am a beginner programmer.

I wrote following code and I want to compare the lenght of the Track ID (which is in my data set) with the Track ID (which is extracted from the web page) which both are highlighted.(my data set has two fields(user id-track id), i want to compare this track id with the track id which is return from web page)

I want to to it like:

```
if (client.Contains(Convert.ToString(TrackID))&&row["TrackID"].lenght=Track ID.lenght)
```

Thank you

Code:

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Net;

namespace test2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\hidden.accdb";
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from hidden.accdb";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //To read data from dataset
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            //Store the UserID
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            int UserID=0,TrackID=0;
            int counter=0;
            foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                string url = "http://abcd/<userid>?groups=<userid>";
                var test = url.Replace("<userid>", Convert.ToString(row["UserID"]));
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
                string client = (new WebClient()).DownloadString("http://abcd/UserID?groups=UserID");
                if (client.ToLower() == (Convert.ToString(TrackID).ToLower()))
                {
                    counter++;
                }
                int ave = counter / 2916;
                MessageBox.Show("Average" + counter);
            }
            conn.Close();
            }

}
}
```

Comment: Convert both to strings (if they're not already) and then `string1.length == string2.length` will be true if they are the same length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do this?

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    string url = "http://abcd/<userid>?groups=<userid>";
                    var test = url.Replace("<userid>", Convert.ToString(row["UserID"]));
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
                    string client = (new WebClient()).DownloadString("http://abcd/UserID?groups=UserID");
                    if (client.ToLower() == Convert.ToString(TrackID).ToLower())
                    {
                        counter++;
                    }
```